# Setting variables with custom class using Websockets and vapor

Tags: swift, vapor

I am trying to setup a simple vapor web socket. My issue is that I need to maintain the web sockets that are open. In order to do that they need to be stored in a variable. Here is my current code:

```
import Vapor

var test = [Instance]()

final class Instance {
    var socket:WebSocket
    var message:String = ""
    var id:String = ""
}

extension Droplet {
    func setupRoutes() throws {
        get("hello") { req in
            var json = JSON()
            try json.set("hello", "world")
            return json
        }
    }

    //Socket code goes here as well
}
```

I keep getting an error while trying to run my project saying, `Use of unresolved identifier 'Instance'`, Why am I getting this error and how do I fix it? What is the best practicing while using web sockets with vapor?